# Convert String with a number and string to an INT value C#

Tags: c#

I have a value of money such as `$40,000`. I want to convert this to a `int`. 
I already tried `int.Parse(number)`, `int.TryParse()`, and 
`Convert.ToInt32()`, but non work.

How can I convert `$40,000` to `40000` as an `int` value?

Comment: First remove the `$` and the `,`, then parse it.

Comment: Parse as `Decimal` (`double`) then cast to `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse as `decimal` (`double`) then cast to `int`:

```
  string source = "$40,000";

  Decimal money = Decimal.Parse( 
    source,                               // source should be treated as
    NumberStyles.Currency,                // currency 
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")); // of the United States

  // truncation: 3.95 -> 3
  int result = (int)money; 
  // rounding: 3.95 -> 4
  // int result = (int)(money > 0 ? money + 0.50M : money - 0.50M);
```

Or if you are sure that no *cents* can appear (say, `"$39,999.95"` or `"$40,000.05"`)

```
  string source = "$40,000";

  int result = int.Parse( 
    source,                               // source should be treated as
    NumberStyles.Currency,                // currency 
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")); // of the United States
```

Answer (score -2):

```
string moneyAmount = "$40,000";
moneyAmount = moneyAmount.Replace("$", "").Replace(",", "");

return int.Parse(moneyAmount);
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).